# symfony2 getting route parameters (controller arguments vs request)

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, routes, controller

Which access to route parameters is faster?

1. Put route parameters as controller arguments
2. Getting route parameters from `$this->getRequest()->get('param')`

And what about request object? Better way is put request object as controller parameter or call `getRequest()` method on controller object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One could argue that since you need to pull `Request` object from container it's slower approach, but I've done both and difference is negligible. When you need `Request` object it's better to put it as the controller method argument, because you'll have it immediately and PHP Type Hinting will provide additional info (autocomplete and so on) in decent IDEs (I personally recommend PHPStorm). This applies also to other controller method arguments, you are given straight variables, no need to pull them twice from other places.

```
class SthController extends Controller
  {
  public function indexAction(Request $request, $arg1, $arg2)
    {
    // you have $request object with type hint and all goodness
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thx. And what about passing parameters from controller to twig template - which way is faster pass parameters from controller, or get parameters in twig template by `{{ app.request.get('name') }}`?

Comment: As for the performance, same rules apply (`app.request.get` translates directly to something like `$container->get('request')->get('name')`). But for the coding style, you shouldn't rely on `app` variable since it's not available in all situations (try experimenting with ESI, template includes or so and you'll end in the same position as me months ago) - the best way is to send all data you need computed before the render template request.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use getRequest() method because it's more dynamic !

Comment: `getRequest()` is just a shortcut for `$this->container->get('request')` but getting Request object from action parameters is DI approach that should probably be preferred.

In fact there is no `getRequest()` method if you use controller as a service.